# Howcome my code runs in the VBA module, but not when I assign a button click to it?

Tags: vba, module, format, percentage, buttonclick

My code will run correctly when I execute it from the vba code module. However, when I try to assign a button click to it and run it, it does not. For instance, when using the code module I return the correct percentages; but with the button click, I get 0.00% and #VALUE!. I cant figure out why this is.

My code is:

```
Sub ConvertReturns()

Worksheets(2).Range("A1:AQ1000").Copy (Worksheets(5).Range("A1:AQ1000"))

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets(5).Range("B2:AQ1000")
rng = Evaluate(rng.Address & "/100")

Worksheets(5).Range("B2:AQ1000").NumberFormat = "0.00%"

Worksheets(5).Columns("A:AQ").AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: `Evaluate(rng.Address & "/100")` is evaluating the formula on the active sheet.  Change that line to `rng = Worksheets(5).Evaluate(rng.Address & "/100")`

Answer (score 0):

As justin wrote in the comment, always specify the worksheet to operate on:

```
Sub ConvertReturns()
    Dim rng As Range
    With Worksheets(5)
        Worksheets(2).Range("A1:AQ1000").Copy (.Range("A1:AQ1000"))
        Set rng = .Range("B2:AQ1000")
        rng = .Evaluate(rng.Address & "/100")
        .Range("B2:AQ1000").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        .Columns("A:AQ").AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```